# this attempt to set a cookie was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid - Laravel on prod only

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, axios, session-cookies

Currently I have a Laravel REST API as my backend, the Set-Cookie is not being run because of the error mentioned above.

[image]

My frontend application is hosted on vercel, let's assume the url is `https://myapp.vercel.app`, and my backend api is hosted on DigitalOcean Nginx ubuntu (let's assume the URL is `192.169.0.1`, fake ip), I don't have a domain name), it has a self-signed SSL and the cors is working fine as all the GET request works perfectly fine, POST request does not and it will result in a error of `CSRF-token mismatch`

I've tried changing the domain name on the server `.env` file multiple times to different names such as
`myapp.vercel.app`
`.vercel.app`
but none of them are working. I've also attempted changing the `samesite` option to `none` or even omitted it from the server dotenv.

This issue does not happen on my development localhost server, currently I can't afford for a domain name for the backend, so I would like to have the answers revolving around my restrictions.

I've also did my research from multiple post available from the internet and consulted chatgpt but to no avail, any help would be appreciated